# Media Foundation SourceReader returns empty data

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I want to create a class responsible for reading compressed video data from an MP4 file using SourceReader from Media Foundation. I've written a method to read a single sample, and it runs without any errors, but the data in the buffer is always empty. I followed the tutorial below for guidance:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/processing-media-data-with-the-source-reader

I've already checked the file validation, and everything seems fine. Additionally, I've attempted to configure the SourceReader with both the native MediaType and one that was manually configured. Here is my code:

```
HRESULT MfVideoReader::Initialize(std::string filePath) {
    try {
        std::wstring wsFilePath = StringHelper::str2wstr(filePath);
        throw_if_fail(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(wsFilePath.c_str(), NULL, &pSourceReader));
        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->GetNativeMediaType(0, 0, &pOutputMediaType));
        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->SetCurrentMediaType(0, NULL, pOutputMediaType));
        return S_OK;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        Logger::log_error("Fail to initialize the video source reader", e.what());
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}

HRESULT MfVideoReader::ReadFrame(BYTE* frameData, LONGLONG* pSampleTime) {
    try {
        CComPtr<IMFSample> pSample;
        DWORD stream = 0;
        DWORD streamFlags = 0;
        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->ReadSample(0, 0, &stream, &streamFlags, pSampleTime, &pSample));
        
        CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> pMediaBuffer;
        throw_if_fail(pSample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &pMediaBuffer));

        BYTE* pData = nullptr;
        DWORD maxLength = 0;
        DWORD dataSize = 0;
        throw_if_fail(pMediaBuffer->Lock(&pData, &maxLength, &dataSize));
        memcpy(frameData, pData, dataSize);
        throw_if_fail(pMediaBuffer->Unlock());

        return S_OK;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        Logger::log_error("Fail to read a sample", e.what());
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's necessary to [Configure the source reader to get uncompressed data from the source file](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/AudioClip/main.cpp#L168).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried to do this like in the example above, but unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code according to [Microsoft's example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/AudioClip) related to reading an audio stream and writing it to a file. After the modifications, the code looks as follows:

```
HRESULT MfVideoReader::Initialize(const std::string& filePath) {
    try {
        std::wstring wsFilePath = StringHelper::str2wstr(filePath);
        throw_if_fail(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(wsFilePath.c_str(), NULL, &pSourceReader));
        
        CComPtr<IMFMediaType> pUncompressedVideoType;
        CComPtr<IMFMediaType> pPartialType;

        throw_if_fail(MFCreateMediaType(&pPartialType));
        throw_if_fail(pPartialType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
        throw_if_fail(pPartialType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12));

        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, NULL, pPartialType));
        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &pUncompressedVideoType));
        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->SetStreamSelection((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, TRUE));

        return S_OK;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        Logger::log_error("Fail to initialize the video source reader", e.what());
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}

HRESULT MfVideoReader::ReadFrame(BYTE* frameData, LONGLONG* pSampleTime) {
    try {
        CComPtr<IMFSample> pSample;
        DWORD streamFlags = 0;
        throw_if_fail(pSourceReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, NULL, &streamFlags, pSampleTime, &pSample));

        CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> pMediaBuffer;
        BYTE* pData = NULL;
        DWORD cbBuffer = 0;
        throw_if_fail(pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pMediaBuffer));
        throw_if_fail(pMediaBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, &cbBuffer));
        memcpy(frameData, pData, cbBuffer);
        throw_if_fail(pMediaBuffer->Unlock());

        return S_OK;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        Logger::log_error("Fail to read a sample", e.what());
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}
```

After performing tests, I noticed that not all video formats are supported in this case. Here is the list of supported video formats:

- MFVideoFormat_H264,
- MFVideoFormat_I420,
- MFVideoFormat_IYUV,
- MFVideoFormat_NV12,
- MFVideoFormat_YUY2,
- MFVideoFormat_YV12.

For the H264 format, no flag is set and the data is empty. For I420, IYUV, NV12, YUY2 and YV12 formats, the MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED flag is set and data is returned correctly.